# Getting the WebDavURL from Tridion Anguilla in the List View

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I would like to get the WebDavURL property of an item int he listview using Anguilla for a GUI Extension.

I have the following code but WebDavURL is not returned:

```
selectedItem = selection.getItems()[0];
var item = $models.getItem(selectedItem);
var webDavUrl = item.getInfo().webDavUrl();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to actually load the webDavUrl... item.loadWebDavUrl().  You'll have to set an event handler though to notify once the WebDav URL has been loaded as its an asynchronous method.  Here's a sample that includes loading and setting an event handler:

```
var item = $models.getItem(selectedItem),
    webDavUrl = item.getWebDavUrl();

if (!webDavUrl) {
    // WebDavUrl for cached item hasn't been loaded yet, so lets load it.
    $evt.addEventHandler(item, "loadwebdavurl", function (event) {
        webDavUrl = item.getWebDavUrl(); // also could do event.source.getWebDavUrl()
    });
    item.loadWebDavUrl();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Would it be worth the extra effort to also remove the event handler, once the webdavurl has been loaded? Or is there no need to do that in this case?

Comment: Hi Frank, I think it definitely could be worth the effort, since the item's event handlers also get cached just like the other properties.  If somewhere within the cache's scope  (I believe any extension running within same window?) the item is opened up, and the webdav url is loaded without checking that it had already been loaded, your event handler would be executed there as well.